# Unbounded subsequence leads to unbounded sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose we have a sequence $\{t_k\}_{k\geq 0}$ with $\sup_k t_k = \infty$. If $|t_{k+1} - t_k| \leq c$ for a constant $c>0$, can we say that $\lim_k t_k \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot conclude this. Here is a "handwavy" counter-example (since having a closed formula would be a little tedious to write, and to understand) :

Consider $f$ as a concatenation of hats functions such that $|f'|=c$ wherever $f'$ is defined, then, make each one of these hat function larger than the previous one as you progress toward $\infty$, then all conditions are fullfilled but there will always be some points close to $0$ located after every positive $x$.

For $c=1$, that would give something like this for example :

$$t=(0,1,0,1,2,1,0,1,2,3,2,1,0, \dots)$$

Comment: Thanks, I think I get the gist of the answer.